# Binding to a WPF custom control dependency property

Tags: wpf, binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I am having a hard time binding a property of a wpf custom control. 
Here is an excerp of my xaml custom datagrid cell whose datacontext is the list(of date):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start" MinWidth="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <timePicker:CustomTimePicker selectedTime="{Binding Path=startDate}" MinWidth="100" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

As you can see, I try to bind the startDate Property of my List(Of Date) to the selectedTime dependency property in my custom wpf control TimePicker. 
Here is the definition of the customtimepicker class with the selectedDate dependency-property:

```
Public Class CustomTimePicker

Private _hours As String
Private _minutes As String


Private _hoursChoices As List(Of String)
Private _minutesChoices As List(Of String)

Public Shared selectedTimeProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("selectedTime", GetType(Date), GetType(CustomTimePicker), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf CustomTimePicker.OnSelectedTimeChanged)))

Public Property selectedTime() As Date
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(selectedTimeProperty), Date)
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        SetValue(selectedTimeProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property hours As String
    Get
        Return _hours
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _hours = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property minutes As String
    Get
        Return _minutes
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _minutes = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property hoursChoices As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _hoursChoices
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        _hoursChoices = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property minutesChoices As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _minutesChoices
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        _minutesChoices = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Shared Sub OnSelectedTimeChanged(ByVal obj As DependencyObject, ByVal args As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("@@@@@@@")
    Console.WriteLine(CType(obj, CustomTimePicker).selectedTime.ToString)
End Sub

Protected Shared Sub OnCoerce()

End Sub

Protected Sub OnSelectedHourChanged(obj As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles hourComboBox.SelectionChanged
    Dim minute As Integer = 0

    Dim result As Date = New Date(2000, 1, 1, hourComboBox.SelectedIndex, selectedTime.Minute, 0)
    selectedTime = result

    Console.WriteLine("---")
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine(selectedTime.ToString)

End Sub

Protected Sub OnSelectedMinuteChanged(obj As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles minutesComboBox.SelectionChanged
    Dim minute As Integer = 0
    Console.WriteLine("bbbbbb")
    Console.WriteLine(selectedTime.ToString)
    Select Case minutesComboBox.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            minute = 0
        Case 1
            minute = 15
        Case 2
            minute = 30
        Case 3
            minute = 45
    End Select

    Dim result As Date = New Date(2000, 1, 1, selectedTime.Hour, minute, 0)
    selectedTime = result
End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub OnInitialized(e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnInitialized(e)
    _hoursChoices = New List(Of String)
    _minutesChoices = New List(Of String)

    Console.WriteLine("aaaaaaa")
    Console.WriteLine(selectedTime.ToString)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 23
        _hoursChoices.Add(i.ToString)
    Next
    _minutesChoices.Add("00")
    _minutesChoices.Add("15")
    _minutesChoices.Add("30")
    _minutesChoices.Add("45")

    hourComboBox.ItemsSource = hoursChoices
    hourComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = hours
    hourComboBox.SelectedValuePath = hours
    hourComboBox.SelectedValue = hours

    minutesComboBox.ItemsSource = minutesChoices
    minutesComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = minutes
    minutesComboBox.SelectedValuePath = minutes
    minutesComboBox.SelectedValue = minutes



    Select Case selectedTime.Minute
        Case 0 To 14
            minutesComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
        Case 15 To 29
            minutesComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1
        Case 30 To 44
            minutesComboBox.SelectedIndex = 2
        Case 45 To 59
            minutesComboBox.SelectedIndex = 3
    End Select

    hourComboBox.SelectedIndex = selectedTime.Hour

End Sub
```

End Class

If I change the selectedTime property for example by

```
selectedTime = New Date(2000,1,1,23,59,0)
```

the value does not change in the datagrid. It is the same problem the other way around. I do not get the startTime values to the wpf control.

It really seems like the binding is not working, even though the application compiles and runs error free.

Can somebody help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Does the owner of the startDate property implement INotifyPropertyChanged (or the equivalent for VB)? Are you seeing any binding error message in the output window of visual studio?

Comment: No it does. In this case the owner of startDate is a class which is defined in a wcf service, so I guess there is no chance to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Unfortunatly, I even dont get the custom controls selectedDate Property to become the value of the start Date in the first place. Binding error see abaove. But I dont understand why.

Comment: I had a spelling mistake, which caused the binding error. How ever spelling it correctly doessolve the binding errors but not the problem of no binding.

Comment: You could always wrap that class in a viewmodel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, if you can get the binding to work

Comment: Ok. But isnt it the next step. First of all I need to establish a connection between the custom control and the startdate property, dont I?

Comment: Well on that i can't help. Assuming the DataGrid contains items with a startDate property of type Date defined, then i don't see anything wrong with your code